# How can I get the world coordinates of the node of the gltf model in cesium, such as a plane.gltf, I want to get the world coordinates of the wheel

Tags: cesiumjs

How can I get the world coordinates of the node of the gltf model in cesium, such as a plane.gltf, I want to get the world coordinates of the wheel？

（1）load glb

```
cesium.primitiveFighter = cesium.viewer.scene.primitives.add(
          Cesium.Model.fromGltf({
            url: "f18_v13.glb",
            modelMatrix: modelMatrix,
            scale: 20.0,
            minimumPixelSize: 16,
            maximumScale: 300,
          })
        );
```

(2) get node
var node = model.getNode("wheel");

(3) matrix transformaton

```
 node.matrix =
              Cesium.Matrix4.fromTranslationQuaternionRotationScale(
                new Cesium.Cartesian3(
                  element.cannonBody.position.x,
                  element.cannonBody.position.y,
                  element.cannonBody.position.z
                ), // translation
                element.cannonBody.quaternion, // rotation
                new Cesium.Cartesian3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), // scale
                element.cesiumNode.matrix
              );
```

（4）
How to get the world coordinates after node transformation？
My idea is to get the mesh corresponding to the node, but it seems that I can't get it

Answer (score 0):

you can get the modelNode's world transform by `node._runtimeNode.computedMatrix`